# How to bypass 20 item limitation in clipboard?

Tags: keyboard

The Android clipboard by default has a limitation of twenty items.

How can this limitation be bypassed?

For dessktop PCs, there is Ditto clipboard. But for mobile phones, there is nothing like that, as far as I know.

Mobile phones are heavily restricted compared to desktop PCs.

Comment: @beeshyams I would like to upvote your comment, but I can not see the upvote button. Do I need some reputation to do that?

Comment: I see, @beeshyams. I already have the small triangle on RC.SE (retrocomputing). But I have 20 reputation there.

Comment: A list of your "nothing" can be found on my Android site: [Clipboard Tools](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard). Quite a lot of nothing, by the way :) @beeshyams could write up an answer which you then could accept (resulting in +2 for you – getting you closer to the [vote-up privilege](/help/privileges/vote-up)).

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of apps  that can store far more than 20. Search for*Clipboard* on Play Store . One such app <s>which doesn't require extra / suspicious permissions</s> is [Clipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper) which I found to be very effective in organising clipboard

You will find plenty more apps in [Clipboard Tools](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard), from the curated repository maintained by Izzy , as he noted in comments . Also note that Izzy has pointed out better alternatives in his now deleted comments, needing fewer permissions:

> [Clipper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.rojekti.clipper) requires permissions to "test access to protected storage, modify or delete the contents of your USB storage, view network connections, full network access, receive data from Internet, receive cloud messages, run at startup". From a privacy point-of-view, all those network permissions should *not* be there as they are certainly not required for the functionality of a clipboard: Keep in mind you might copy sensitive information like passwords. Not saying the app intentionally does something bad here – but who knows what some integrated ad/tracking library might do (Clipper contains at least 3 of them)?
>
> So better choices would probably include:
>
> - [My Clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wb.myclipboard): only requests "run at startup, reorder running apps, draw over other apps". Not sure why it needs to "reorder running apps" – but at least it doesn't ask for network access, so the danger of transmitting sensitive data is much lower (if existing at all).
> - [CopyClip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.copyclip): only requests "draw over other apps, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" – perfectly understandable, as it needs to draw its action buttons (for copy/paste) on top of the app you're copy/pasting from/to.